# SQL Error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 --ERROR WHILE INSERTING RECORD INTO TABLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i am trying to insert a record in to a table  below is the insert script , I am getting Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 error , please help.

```
INSERT INTO  ABC.ENTRY_TABLE
        (D_ID, CD, DSC, EMAIL_DL_ID, SUBJECT_QUERY, BODY_QUERY, 
        ATTACHMENT_QUERY, ATTACHMENT_NAME, RECORD_COUNT_RESTRICTION,
        CREATE_DT, CREATE_BY, UPDATE_DT, UPDATE_BY, SEND_EMAIL_FLG,
        ATTACHMENT_FLAG_QUERY  )
VALUES( (select max(D_ID)+1 from ABC.ENTRY_TABLE),
        'TEST','TEST report',
        (select max(EMAIL_DL_ID)+1 from ABC.ENTRY_TABLE),
        'select case when row_count > 1 then 'TEST: Missing Records' else 'TEST: No Missing Records' end from (select count(*) row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)',
        'select case when row_count > 1 then 'Attached are  Missing Records' else 'No Missing Records' end from (select count(*) row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)',
        NULL,SYSDATE,'TEST',SYSDATE,'TEST',
        'SELECT 'Y' FROM DUAL',
        'select case when row_count > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end from (select count(*) row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)'
    );
```

Updated query:

```
INSERT INTO  ABC.ENTRY_TABLE
(
D_ID 
, CD 
, DSC  
, EMAIL_DL_ID 
, SUBJECT_QUERY  
, BODY_QUERY 
, ATTACHMENT_QUERY  
, ATTACHMENT_NAME 
, RECORD_COUNT_RESTRICTION 
, CREATE_DT 
, CREATE_BY  
, UPDATE_DT 
, UPDATE_BY  
, SEND_EMAIL_FLG  
, ATTACHMENT_FLAG_QUERY  )
VALUES(
 (select max(D_ID)+1 from ABC.ENTRY_TABLE)
 ,'TEST'
 ,'TEST report'
 ,(select max(EMAIL_DL_ID)+1 from ABC.ENTRY_TABLE)
,'select case when row_count > 1 then 'TEST: Missing Records' else 'TEST: No Missing Records' end from (select count(*) row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)'
,'select case when row_count > 1 then 'Attached are  Missing Records' else 'No Missing Records' end from (select count(*) row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)'
,NULL
,'Missing_Records.csv'
,null
,SYSDATE
,'TEST'
,SYSDATE
,'TEST'
,'SELECT 'Y' FROM DUAL'
,'select case when row_count > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end from (select count(*) row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)'
 );
```

Comment: Which database are you using

Comment: right, i was missign 2 of them , but even after  correcting i stil face the same issue.

Comment: then post your updated query

Comment: The weird syntax colouring is a very obvious sign that you've mixed up strings and statements. You have  a string `'select case when row_count > 1 then '` followed by the invalid statement  `TEST: Missing Records`. Your editor's syntax colouring probably already warned you about this

Comment: Srini, iam using oracle SQl developer

Comment: @gowtami then don't use irrelevant tags. There's nothing more annoying than trying to answer a question than finding you were given misleading information. And fix the strings

Comment: There's an issue with the quotes inside the select statements you want to save. Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have 15 columns in your insert but you select only 13 values. 
You seem to be missing values for attachment name and record_count_restriction.

Edit. You need to double the '' inside the queries you want to insert.

```
,'select case when row_count > 1 
                    then ''Attached are Missing Records'' 
                  else ''No Missing Records'' 
                  end 
           from (select count() row_count from DDD.TOTAL_RCORDS)'
```

also

```
,'SELECT ''Y'' FROM DUAL'
```

etc.